# What does onDelete('cascade') mean?

Tags: php, laravel

```php
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Does this mean that if I delete a post, the user will also be deleted or does it mean if I delete a user, all their posts will be deleted?

Comment: ">onDelete" should be "->onDelete" and you have double ";;"

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The short answer is: in your case if you deleted a `user`, all posts related to him will be deleted too.

`onDelete('cascade');` simply adds the `ON DELETE CASCADE` rule to your database which specifies that the child data gets deleted when the parent data is deleted.

Note: take care of the typo (double semicolon)

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Also, the Laravel function uses delete cascade

```
`$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: Good answer. If a record in the `on()` table gets deleted, these associated foreign key records will also get deleted. Also note that `foreign()` cannot be chained to a column creation statement.

Comment: @Ryan what if I dont want to delete the associated record but just unlink the foreign key when the record in the main table gets deleted?

Comment: Also, use Laravel function to delete cascade 

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->cascadeOnDelete();

Answer (score 16):

The code you are talking about creates a foreign key / reference to a column on another table. The `onDelete('cascade')` means that when the row is deleted, it will delete all it's references and attached data too.

For example if you have a User which has a Post and you set onDelete('cascade') on the user, then when the user deletes his account, all posts will be deleted as well.

You can find more information on [Laravel excellent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. When a user has multiple posts, then the child table is the post and the parent table is the user. As foreign key constraints are always defined on the child table, it will be defined on the posts table. Hence, the `onDelete('cascade')` will be defined on the *user* table, not the *posts* table. Only then will the deletion of a user cascade to cause a deletion of all of her posts.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using mysql, take a look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

In your case it means: If the user is deleted, the post will also be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

It means that if you delete the 'user' linked, the 'posts' linked to that user will also automatically be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

There are two tables **users**(parent table) and **posts**(children table). So if data is **deleted in users table** then the data in users will get **deleted as well as their children's data** i.e posts.

But if the data is deleted in the **posts** table, it does not mean data from the **users** table gets deleted. It's a one-way process and it also makes sense that if the user's post is deleted, it does not **signifies to delete the user details**(from the table) but **if the user details get deleted** then all the post-related to it will not have any meaning.

So we beforehand write this **ON DELETE CASCADE in the migration** files mentioning the proper foreign keys.