# Deleteing data from multiple tables depending relationship in Laravel Vuejs Api

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel, vue.js, axios

i have two tables Company and Employee

both in relationship Company is parent tble and Employees is child table.

now i need to delete record from parent table which in turn must delete all the relevant child table.

how to do this?

it gives me the below error

> message: "No query results for model [App\Employee] 2"

Modal code is:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
             $table->string('BadgeCode')->unique();
              $table->integer('company_id');
              $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

API code is:

```
Route::apiResources(['company'=>'API\CompanyController']);
```

Code in CompanyController is:

```
 public function destroy($id)
    {
         $this->authorize('isAdmin');
        $user = Company::findOrFail($id);
        Employee::where('company_id',$id)->delete();
        $user->delete();
        return ['message'=>'Company Deleted Successfully'];
    }
```

My Company.Vue Scriptcode:

```
deletecompany(id) {
      if (this.$gate.isAdmin()) {
        swal
          .fire({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
            cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
          })
          .then(result => {
            //Send request to the server

            if (result.value) {
              this.form
                .delete("api/company"/" + id)
                .then(() => {
                  // swal.fire("Deleted!", "Your file has been deleted.", "success");
                  toast.fire({
                    type: "success",
                    title: "Your Selected Company is successfully deleted!"
                  });
                  Fire.$emit("refreshPage");
                })
                .catch(e => {
                  console.log(e);
                });
            }
          });
      } else {
        toast.fire({
          type: "error",
          title: "You don't permission to perform this action!"
        });
        Fire.$emit("refreshPage");
      }
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<a href="#" v-if="$gate.isAdmin()" @click="deletecompany(company.id)">
                      <i class="fa fa-trash red"></i>
                    </a>
```

Comment: hmmm if this is always the case why no delete on cascade ?

Comment: or maybe overwrite the delete method in you model to call  `$this->employees()->delete();` and aftert parent::delete()

Comment: you mean like this  $user = Company::findOrFail($id);
        
        $user->delete();
        Employee::where('company_id',$id)->delete();
        $this->employees()->delete();
        return ['message'=>'Company Deleted Successfully'];

Comment: Your error message usually only occurs when you do `Employee::findOrFail($id)`. Do you have a call like that anywhere? I don't see it in your code. Also do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Also a cleaner way is to use the [Observer pattern](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers) in laravel. That way you can remove the `Employee::delete()` call from the `CompanyController` and move it to its own `CompanyObserver::deleted()` function.

Comment: now it gives me this message message: "This action is unauthorized."          $user = Company::find($id);
       Employee::where('company_id',$id)->delete();
        $user->delete();
        // 
        // $this->employees()->delete();
        return ['message'=>'Company Deleted Successfully'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a reference for `company_id` and `onDelete(cascade)` in your migration See this link [What does onDelete('cascade') mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094543/what-does-ondeletecascade-mean), When you delete a company, It will delete all the employees associated with that company automatically.

```html
public function up() {
    Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('BadgeCode')->unique();
        $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: This have to do with `$this->authorize('isAdmin');`, Try remove this line in your controller and see if it works. It means the user is not authorized to delete the resource. Log in as the admin first before trying to delete

Comment: yes you are right I removed it and it works Thank You